# MATLAB: Forming an array of matrices and do operations with respect to each matrix "element"

Tags: matlab, optimization, vectorization

I have an array of matrix m such that

```
  m1 = [1 2;3 4];
  m2 = [2 7; 8 9];
  m3 = [9 7; 8 91];
  m = [m1 m2 m3]


m =
       1     2     2     7     9     7
       3     4     8     9     8    91
```

I also have a vector

```
v = [1 2 3];
```

such that i want the operations between v and m result in h such that

```
h = [1*m1 2*m2 3*m3] = [h1 h2 h3];
```

I imagine I have to do this in 3-dimensional array for `h`, which is a 3d array. Or maybe there are better ways.

Let A be a simple 2 by 2 matrix, `rand(2,2)`.
From `h` i want to extract `h1` `h2` and `h3` out(or better not doing any extraction) and perform operations  to `A` such that

1.

```
  h1*A*h1'
  h2*A*h2'
  h3*A*h3'
```

and

2.

```
h1*h1', h2*h2', h3*h3'.
```

Why i want to do this in array is because i have a lot of matrix mi so I want to avoid for loop by vectorization.

Comment: You might want to make `m` 2x2x3 onstead of 2x6. Would that work with your problem? I'm not sure it will help but look at the bsxfun (or something like that) command. Never underestimate a for loop for doing your multiplication, but it is always fun to vectorize ;)

Answer (score 0):

From what i could understand from the question, i suppose element-wise multiplication would be better choice. You would just have to use proper concatenation and repeatation of matrices.

```
  m1 = [1 2; 3 4];
  m2 = [2 7; 8 9];
  m3 = [9 7; 8 91];

  % Concatenate to create 3D matrix
  m = cat(3,m1,m2,m3);

  v = [1 2 3];

  % Create similar 3D matrix 
  v1 = cat(3,ones(size(m1))*v(1),ones(size(m2))*v(2),ones(size(m3))*v(3));

  % Simple element wise multiplication
  h = m.*v1;

  % Creating a repeated 3D matrix A, repetation is along third dimension
  A = repmat(rand(2,2),[1 1 3]);

  % Outputs
  op_1 = h.*A.*permute(h,[2 1 3]);
  op_2 = h.*permute(h,[2 1 3]);
```